# Why can't new group members see a folder that I have shared with the group?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, google-drive-sharing, google-drive-shared-folder

I have a folder that I am sharing with a Google Apps group, `marketing@acme.org`

When I add a new user to the group via the "Groups" section in the Google Apps admin panel, I expect the shared folder to be automatically shared to the new group member as well. However, the new user doesn't see it.

While troubleshooting this behavior I noted that:

1. Sharing a folder to the group automatically shares the folder with all existing group members, but not to users who are added to the group after the folder is shared.
2. If I unshare the folder from the group, then re-share it to the group, it will again be shared with all existing group members, including the newly added user who was previously excluded.

In the Admin interface under "[Group List](https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?fral=1#GroupList)" the type is displayed as "*team (domain)* or *team (internet)*"

What do I have to do when a new employee is added to the marketing team in order for them to also automatically get access to the shared folder?

Comment: @pnuts so you're saying that it should change but not immediately ? If so then great, but i've waited some time and it didn't seem to change.

Comment: Waiting didn't seem to do the trick for me. Maybe I haven't waited long enough. I'm adding the users in Google Apps admin panel in the usual place ... When sharing in drive, I share the whole group and not specific people - `marketing@acme.org`. When I share, the users already in the group will have access to the folder, but if I add users after I shared, they will not see the folder

Comment: Have been struggling with this recently and it seems like the user must accept the invitation sent to his Gmail account before he/she can see shared company drives/folders/files.

Comment: I had a similar issue, turns out the users had access, but the shared drive was hidden. They can go to the shared drive page, click on Hidden Shared Drives on the top right and right-click -> unhide the desired drive

Answer (score 5):

I had the very same problem. This worked for me:
I am admin of groups A and B of google accounts. Groups have some privileges on some folders. I add Bob to group B. Bob gains all privileges that group B has.

THEN

Bob logs in Drive. He must search for the most rooted folder that group B has some privilege on. To do the search, search bar at top is used, the one inside Drive page.

Once that folder's name displays is the bar suggestions, Bob clicks on it. In my scenario, Google first gave an error, saying something like "Folder cannot be located". 
Then the folder appeared as expected. As always, adding it to My-Drive eases all the thing, so that Bob access is permanent.

If i'm not mistaken, add-to-my-drive button appears also in the search bar, beside folder's name, when it's found, at mouse hoover.

Hope this helps!